# Can't start MariaDB or MySQL on CentOS7.4

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I tried to run mariaDB or MySQL on CentOS7.4. It was successful to start mariaDB and I had to change the configuration to allow remote access but during the process, I uninstalled mariadb/mysql and reinstalled it.
Since then I'm not able to start either mariaDB or MySQL. I have uninstalled and reinstalled both packages multiple times following instructions from multiple web sources using yum/rpm method and no fail or issues found during the installation. But no luck to start/enable mariaDB or MySQL yet. below is the message.

```
 [root@localhost mariadb-10.2.13-rhel-7-x86_64-rpms]# sudo systemctl start mariadb
 Failed to start mariadb.service: Unit not found.
```

I'm not sure where to look at first if want to fix this. anyone could guide me to the solution?

Comment: For server questions, please use the [Super User Stack Exchange Site](https://superuser.com/)

Comment: sure, thanks. I already figured out the problem is and fixed it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because (1) belongs elsewhere); (2) Asker found answer but did not share it.